# Android ANSIX923 Cipher Padding

Tags: c#, android

I'm trying to make an android app that connects to a database, there are different users and they all have encrypted passwords. I have created a C# application for connecting to the database and it also creates those passwords with the following algorithm:

```
        String PKey = "key";
        int intLenght = textBox1.Text.Length - 1;
        string NewString = null;


        NewString = textBox1.Text;

        byte[] keyArray;
        byte[] ToEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(NewString);
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PKey));
        hashmd5.Clear();
        TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
        tdes.Key = keyArray;
        tdes.Mode = CipherMode.EBC;
        tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.ANSIX923;
        ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(ToEncryptArray, 0, ToEncryptArray.Length);
        tdes.Clear();
        string res = System.Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);

        textBox2.Text = res;
```

I have replicated this in android like so:

```
try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] hash = md.digest(PKey.getBytes("UTF-8")); // <-- note encoding
        byte[] toEncryptByte = encString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESEDE/EBC/X9.23PADDING");
        SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(hash,"DESede");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey);
        byte[] encryptedPlainText = cipher.doFinal(toEncryptByte);

        String encrypted = Base64.encodeToString(encryptedPlainText, 0);

        return encrypted;


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

The problem is is that Android doesn't seem to support EBC ANSIX923 as it throws the error:

```
No provider found for DESEDE/EBC/X9.23PADDING
```

I'm trying to avoid changing the padding mode or cipher mode in C# because I would have to replace all the passwords.

As a test I tried the PKCS7 padding and it worked for both.

Does the EBC ANSIX923 padding exist for android?

Thanks!

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Four poor security choices: 1. Encrypting passwords. 2. 3DES. 3. ECB mode. 4. ANSIX923 padding. Security for your users is important and needs current best practices. Please sir, may we have best practices?